# config.status not found

Tags: linux, make

I'm trying to compile a program from source. When I run `make` the following appears:

```
./config.status --recheck
make: ./config.status: Command not found
make: *** [config.status] Error 127
```

There is no file called config.status in the current directory. Why was it not created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try typing:

```
./configure
```

This will assess your system to determine if all dependencies are satisfied and evaluates how to best compile your program.  If successful, it generates the required files to run `make`, including `config.status`.

Comment: That's what I did. I typed configure and then I typed make.

Comment: Make sure all dependencies are met.  If not, `./configure` will return an error and will not generate `config.status`.  Also, make sure that you typed `./configure` (with dot-slash), not simply `configure`, as this will result in the configure script not being found.

Comment: Yeah, I typed ./configure. It completed without error but didn't make the file.

Comment: If so, then the configure script may be incorrectly written or may have been modified.  Make sure that you have read the documentation on how to build the program.  Try downloading the package and compiling the program again; if this fails, report a bug to the software vendor.